# Are there better strategies to reduce redundancy in test case specifications?

Tags: testing, specifications, testcase

When writing test case specifications I often run into patterns where some actions to be performed by the tester are shared between test cases:

```
Test case 1:
  Action A
  Action B
  Action C

Test case 2:
  Action A
  Action B'
  Action C

Test case 3:
  Action A
  Action B''
  Action C
```

This is a very simple case, in practice, things get much more complicated.

I normally use a combination of two strategies for handling this, both of which are not really satisfying:

1. Don't describe actions A and C in test cases 2 and 3. Instead refer to the action descriptions in test case 1. Problem: This makes the test case descriptions hard to read.
2. Combine test cases 1-3 into a single test case. Problem: In paractice, this can lead to huge test cases.

Is there a better (easier to read, less error prone) way?

Note: These are tests to be performed by a human tester, no test automation.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at hiptest.com - its a tool/platform which allows you to define action words, so you can reference repeated steps in multiple tests. That is the only tool i know which can do this. All other (classical) test management tools only give you free text field to describe your test scenario.